# Get a changeset based on a build ID using the VSTS API

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I need to know which projects are part of a changeset for a specifc build using the VSTS API 2018. The REST api doesn´t seem to support getting a changeset based on a buildId. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/tfvc/changesets/get

Is it possible to get a changeset based on a build ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You're looking at the wrong area of the documentation.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/build/builds/get%20build%20changes

> GET
>   https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/changes?api-version=4.1

That gets you the changes associated with a build. If you want to get more details on the changesets from there, you can retrieve the specific changesets using the API you've already discovered.